# parameter is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: .net, wcf, parameters

I have a test project which contains a service reference to a WCF service and a service project which contains the service code. This has a parameter which is used to return a string value.

```
<OperationContract()> 
Function Action(parameter as String) As Boolean
```

In the test code I declare a variable and it is passed into the service call. After the call completes the value of the parameter is checked.

```
Dim parameter As String = String.Empty
Dim result As Boolean = service.Action(parameter)
Assert.IsTrue(result = True)
Assert.IsTrue(parameter.Length > 0)
```

When I first tested this parameter was still empty after the call to the service so I added `By Ref`  to the function but now when I check the value of it in the Immediate Window I get a `'parameter' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level` error.

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: For those voting to close, please refer to this blog post: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by a simple oversight. when I changed the service interface to switch the parameter from the implied 'By Val' to an explicit 'By Ref' I **didn't update the service reference** in my test project.

Once I'd updated the service reference it worked fine.